# how to connect database using uLink MMO with RPC

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new on Unity and uLink MMO.

I am developing 3D game. In this project I need to connect mySQL database.
I have done the database connectivity using following method.
1. Made web service in C#.net. This is returning me data in Json format. Database connection string is in web service.
2. Read the Json output using Unity C# file.

Now I want to connect database using uLink+RPC.
Is there any way to connect database using RPC (without web service and uGameDB).

Please tell me the step or over all scenario to connect database using uLink + RPC.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Bharat

Answer (score 1):

All database communication with mySQL should be done 
asynchronously, otherwise your game server will pause until it gets an answer 
and the server's frames per second (FPS) will drop to zero until the database gives an answer.

How you make it asynchronous is up to you. Just make sure the Unity server's main thread
isn't stopped while it waits for the database to reply.

As long as you stick with mySQL you could try one of these solutions.

1. Use the asynchronous API for mysql. Use MySQL Connector/Net.
   The Asynchronous API is described here:
   http://mysql-connector-net.sourcearchive.com/documentation/6.1.2-1/classMySql_1_1Data_1_1MySqlClient_1_1MySqlCommand.html
2. Start one or several threads to handle the communication with mysql. This way you can use several parallel "normal" connections to mysql without stopping the main thread in Unity. The hard part is to implement the callbacks when the answer arrives from the database.

None of these ways are without challenges.

We (Muchdifferent, makers of uLink) might publish some examples of how to do solution nr 1 in the future, but at the moment we are focusing on releasing uGameDB instead.

/David

Comment: Thnaks for the reply. Is there any way to connect database using uLink MMO